# Opening .jnlp and getting Error of JRE version

Tags: java, jnlp

I want to open a .jnlp and I get ""Application requires JRE 1.1"". But it's a very old version and it's impossible to download it.Have you any idea,please?

Comment: Web Start was added in Java 5; are you certain your jnlp file is valid?

Comment: Have you any JRE installed on your system?

Comment: @triplem yes, jre 9.0.4

Comment: I am facing issues while opening in offline mode. It says The applications has requested to go online. Do you want to continue?. Any idea? I am using JDK 1.8.0_112. Please help

Comment: @Raushan I deletet all java files and installed Oracle Java 8 (I think it was Java SE Development Kit 8).Then I  run IcedTea and it's ok.But for your problem I am not sure,if this will resolveor not